# I need a roller setting where I input a 1 feet fabric and need it to be reduced and compressed about 9 inches and released back as 1 feet fabric

Tags: design, cad

I have a requirement where I need to input 1 ft wide flexible 5mm thick fabric into a roller setting where my width is reduced to 9 inches and compressed and released back as 1 ft. I thought of using special rollers (which I call Zigzag rollers) for this purpose but the problem I assume is that this setting will tear the fabric. Please help me design it.
The fabric is essentially a loop of 2 ft length.
The Idea is to wet the fabric, clean an object and compress the fabric to collect all the wet dirt and and continue the same process. But since the mechanism has to be on the sides of the rollers I need the width be reduced due to space constraint.

[image]

Comment: Round the corners more and have 2 or 3 sets to progress the fold from initial to final.

Comment: @SolarMike ,  thanks but I did think of that and I wanted to keep the form factor small. The fabric is essentially a loop of 2 ft length.

Comment: Should have been more precise with your question then.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all the relevant details. We can't guess. If you explain *why* you need to do this you may get more useful answers.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I have edited the question.

Comment: what is "the mechanism" that needs to take up three inches?  Are you using these rollers to wring the fabric dry as well?

Answer (score 2):

Papermaking uses rollers called Spreaders to spread the sheet out in the cross-direction (perpendicular to sheet movement).  These are bowed rollers that use friction against the sheet to spread, and I suppose you could use it to compress a sheet.  For such a small scale you would need to build it yourself.

I feel like the design you show will only emboss the fabric, that is, add a z-direction imprint.

Comment: But those are to spread the paper while still wet before it hits the drying rollers and at about 800m/min it’s moving...

Comment: they are used both wet and dry, both on fabric and on a free sheet